# My PUT request isn't working, it returns error 500, I'm not sure why

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to update some data of my database. For that I'm using an ajax request that will change the value of one variable. However this put request isn't working, going straight to the error and giving me an error 500 in the console. Can someone understand why this is happening? 
Here is my ajax request:

```
   function atualizaBD(idmarcador, novoEstado) {
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${idmarcador}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Id: +idmarcador,
                Estado: novoEstado
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);

            },

            error: function () {
                alert("ocorreu um erro!")
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the PUT in my controller:

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao, string novoEstado)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (id != ignicao.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }


        var dataDecisao = DateTime.Now;
        var ig = _context.Ignicoes.FirstOrDefault (ignicaoId => ignicaoId.Id.Equals(id));
        if (ig != null)
        {
            ig.Estado = novoEstado;
            ig.Latitude = ignicao.Latitude;
            ig.Longitude = ignicao.Longitude;
            //esta data vai depender da avaliação de cada uma das ocorrencias 
            ig.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao = ignicao.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao;
            //esta data é colocada quando é definido o estado da ignição (aceite, recusado, em avaliação, concluido)
            ig.DataDecisaoIgnicao = dataDecisao;


        }



        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

The variable that I want to change is Estado to novoEstado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're building an `Ignicoes` object in your AJAX request like this:

```js
{
    Id: +idmarcador,
    Estado: novoEstado
}
```

Then you're updating properties from it on the server like this:

```cs
ig.Latitude = ignicao.Latitude;
ig.Longitude = ignicao.Longitude;
ig.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao = ignicao.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao;
```

Since you're not setting properties `Latitude`, `Longitude`, or `DataInicioPropostaIgnicao` when you build the `Ignicoes` object in your AJAX request, they will always be `null` here.

Second, you *are* setting the `Estado` property in the AJAX request, so you would want to do this on the server:

```cs
ig.Estado = ignicao.Estado;
```

Then you can remove the `string novoEstado` parameter from your `PutIgnicoes` method completely.

If you want to keep the `string novoEstado` parameter, you need to change to something like `[FromQuery] string novoEstado` then change your AJAX request to use:

```js
url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${idmarcador}?novoEstado=${novoEstado}`
```

I suspect the `string novoEstado` parameter is coming into the `PutIgnicoes` method as null (since it's not defined as a query or route parameter). If it is a non-nullable foreign key, the your call to `SaveChangesAsync` wil fail with a foreign key constraint error.